# Performing simple redirect on Blazor Preview 6 Server Side page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I was testing Blazor Server Side in Preview 8 which supports rending of pages on server.  I set up a simple page with a button and simply want it to redirect to another page.

Everywhere I have looked says to use the NavigationManager but this seems to throw an error.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
```

This can be reproduced by simply using the new Blazor Web app template and with the following page.

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager Nav
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm OnValidSubmit="HandleClick" method="POST" Model="formModel">
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</EditForm>
@code{
    private TestModel? formModel = new();
    async Task HandleClick()
    {
        Nav.NavigateTo("ShowData");
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        
    }
}
```

Simply trying to work out how to redirect after dealing with the form.

Am I missing something or using the wrong Navigation method?